# Insurance Application When Exchanging a Drivers License

Tags: driving, documentation, car-insurance

I am exchanging one European driving license for another. Its a simple procedure of sending it away and getting a new one from the county where you are now living. No tests or anything required

When applying for car insurance you are asked your license type and how many years you've had your license.

I'm wondering on this. Is my answer 0. I've just got the local license. Or is it however many years since I've been eligible to drive in this country with a European license?

I know for sure when you change an address or otherwise renew a domestic license it changes nothing with this question. Does it differ if its between countries?

Comment: Is there a way to add this additional information (that you have been licensed by county x for y years, but had to turn in the country x license for an exchange to obtain a country y license) to your insurance application ?

Comment: Field 10 of the driver classes should contain the date for which the class was originally added to the licence (same date for all on first issue).

Comment: Typically what's relevant is how long ago you got your first license and as @MarkJohnson explained, your new license should still mention that date. I don't see any downside in writing that in your application, let them come back to you if need be. It might help to mention the country in the question though, how car insurance works differs quite a bit even in the EU.